# Why is indexedDB is giving an invalid state error?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

when I run this code:

```
var idbSupported = false;
var db;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

    if("indexedDB" in window) {
        idbSupported = true;
    }

    if(idbSupported) {
        var openRequest = indexedDB.open("test",1);

        openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
            console.log("Upgrading...");
        }

        openRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
            console.log("Success!");
            db = e.target.result;
        }

        openRequest.onerror = function(e) {
            console.log("Error: " + e.target.errorCode);
            // console.dir(e);
        }

    }

},false);
```

from this tutorial:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/working-with-indexeddb/

in Firefox 17.

Don't know why I'm getting the error event instead of the success event.

Simplified code gives the same error: ( Just copy-paste ) this into your console see.

```
(function(){
    if(window.indexedDB) {
        var openRequest = indexedDB.open("test", 1);
        openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
            console.log("Upgrading...");
        }
        openRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
            console.log("Success!");
            db = e.target.result;
        }
        openRequest.onerror = function(e) {
            console.log("Error: " + e.target.errorCode);
            console.dir(e);
        }
    }
})();
```

According to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB), FF 16 and up do not need a prefix.

One thing I noted, is that the browser is not asking for permission to use indexedDB as it should so maybe the browser is not configured to use indexedDB?

Comment: Maybe try a higher versionnumber, it is possible the database allready exists in a higher version.

Comment: or just open the database without version number. indexedDB.open("test");

Comment: b.c. it is domain dependent, and I set the domain number, not a strong possibility, but will try it w/ out the domain number.  But indexedDB is supposed to prompt the user for permission, and it did not.  I think this is the bigger suspect.

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure, but I think there were some issues with the first unprefixed version of the indexeddb in Firefox. Maybe try FF 18 and see if you still have the issue

Comment: I'm scrapping this for the same reason I scrapped HTML5 app storage, it supposedly interrupts the user for permission and makes the user paranoid.